# Create a filter for URL that follows a specific format

Tags: java, regex

I have a URL of this form:

```
http://aa-bb.cc-dd-ee.w.x.y.z:8080/funservice/graphql
```

I only want to filter in the requests where `w.x.y.z` is strictly:

```
fun.foo.bar.net
```

I am trying to do with this but I am not quite sure how do I create the regex.

```
private static final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("http(.*?).fun.foo.bar.net(.*?)");

Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString());
while (matcher.find()) {
     for (int j = 0; j <= matcher.groupCount(); j++) {
          String temp = matcher.group(j);
       }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps like `^https?://\S*\.fun\.foo\.bar\.net(?::\d+)?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$` See https://regex101.com/r/cjFaXl/1 In Java you would have to double escape the backslashes like `\\.fun` etc..

Comment: thanks @Thefourthbird! that is working

Comment: Do you have to use a regular expression for this?  `URI.create(httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString()).getHost().endsWith(".fun.foo.bar.net")` will do the same thing.

Comment: @VGR thats a great idea! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example string, you might use:

```
^https?://\S*\.fun\.foo\.bar\.net(?::\d+)?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `https?://` Match the protocol with optional `s`
- `\S*` Match optional non whitespace characters
- `\.fun\.foo\.bar\.net` Match the part of interest (escape the dot to match it literally)
- `(?::\d+)?` Optionally match the port
- `(?:[/?#]\S*)?` Optionally match one of `/` `?` `#` followed by optional non whitespace characters
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cjFaXl/1)

In Java with the doubled backslashes:

```
String regex = "^https?://\\S*\\.fun\\.foo\\.bar\\.net(?::\\d+)?(?:[/?#]\\S*)?$";
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I only want to filter in the requests where `w.x.y.z` is strictly:*
>
> ```
> fun.foo.bar.net
> ```
>
> ... "

You can simplify your code with a *[Matcher#matches](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches())* call, which can be accessed via *[String#matches](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))*.

> *"... I am trying to do with this but I am not quite sure how do I create the regex. ..."*

You can use the following pattern to match the entire text.
For a *match* call, the starting `^` and ending `$` are optional.

```
^http://(?:[^.]+\.){2}fun\.foo\.bar\.net(?::.+|/.*)$
```

As a note, I am presuming you are expecting the *"fun.foo.bar.net"* to follow two *domain-labels*, *"aa-bb.cc-dd-ee."*.
If this isn't the case, change the `{2}` to a `*`.

```
^http://(?:[^.]+\.)*fun\.foo\.bar\.net(?::.+|/.*)$
```

Here is an example.

```java
String s = httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString();
String r = "http://(?:[^.]+\.){2}fun\.foo\.bar\.net(?::.+|/.*)";
boolean match = s.matches(r);
```